# Pattern for converting if-then-else to conditional

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring

What is the **name of this refactoring pattern**? I'd like to read more opinions about it, but can't name it.

The same code is executed in both branches of an if-else-statement, but just one atomic expression is different. E.g.

```java
if (condition) {
    prepareSomethingAdditional();
    callMethod(true, "foobar");
}
else {
    callMethod(false, "foobar");
}
```

This can be refactored, to express that the "callMethod" call is meant to *always* be executed, just the argument shall differ dependening on the condition. E.g.

```java
if (condition) {
    prepareSomethingAdditional();
}
callMethod(condition, "foobar");
```

Of course, this might lead to using a conditional operator as the method argument (if the one different expression is more than a simple true/false), which is another debate.

Comment: A decent, modern compiler probably does something similar through common subexpression elimination (CSE), though I'm not sure that the same term would be used here; I'm still new to the idea that everything I type has been named three times by Martin Fowler.

Comment: I'm not sure if this pattern has a name. On a different subject: passing a boolean to a method is a [bad pattern](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1392524)

Comment: @alfasin, I'm inclined to disagree when the method is "isVisible" or something similar; what would you suggest as a replacement in that situation?

Comment: @Tom `isVisible()` should be a method that accepts no arguments :)

Comment: Can't tell if you're being deliberately obtuse... describe the parameters of a function to set whether an entity be visible or not, please?

Comment: @Tom I'm not trying to annoy you or anything - so I apologize in advance: what you describe sounds to me like `setVisible()` and `setInvisible()` (or `setVisible(true/false)`) - is that what you mean ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70549/discussion-between-tom-and-alfasin).

Comment: There's a problem with the example... what if evaluating condition has a side effect?  Probably the example should be  local_bool=condition; if local_bool ... ; callMethod(local_bool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest pattern I found is Martin Fowler's [Consolidate Duplicate Conditional Fragments](http://refactoring.com/catalog/consolidateDuplicateConditionalFragments.html).

It's not exactly the same thing since the fragment is slightly different, but I think it still can fit under the umbrella in this case.

You could also see it as [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), IMHO.

On another hand, note that passing booleans into functions which are used to control the flow of execution is usually not a good idea, but that's not a golden rule.